# O que acontece com respostas após serem deletadas por um longo período?

Tags: suporte, stackoverflow

Quando excluímos uma resposta aqui no Stack Overflow, ela na realidade é excluída publicamente mas quando eu entro logado na pergunta, a resposta continua lá porém com um background vermelho. Ela ficará marcada como vermelha para sempre, ou aquela resposta vai ser eventualmente apagada?

Comment: Que eu saiba, fica pra sempre (mas só alguém da equipe pode confirmar). Note entretanto que os outros usuários não podem ver sua resposta excluída (a menos que tenham [privilégios](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) suficientes para tal), só você a vê assim. Da mesma forma, você não vê as perguntas/respostas excluídas dos outros usuários, mas elas estão lá. Já comentários excluídos, só os moderadores podem ver (nem mesmo a pessoa que comentou). Esqueci quando se ganha o privilégio de ver postagens excluídas, mas acho que é com 10.000 pontos de reputação.

Comment: E também só é possível encontrá-la com o link específico, pois não aparece no search.

Comment: @brasofilo Exceto [quando você tem 10k e está procurando seus próprios posts](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=deleted%3A1).

Answer (score 2):

Todos os comentários estão certos, mas vale a resposta pra consolidar tudo:

- Posts nunca são realmente **apagados**.
- Posts removidos só podem ser acessados por moderadores, [usuários com 10k](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) e o próprio autor da pergunta.
- Posts removidos só aparecem na busca para moderadores e quando o próprio autor busca seus próprios posts
- Posts removidos aparecem na lista do seu perfil, para você mesmo e moderadores

Acho que é tudo...

Comment: Tem certeza de que posts removidos aparecem na lista do perfil do usuário? Todos os posts? Antes não era assim.

Comment: Ali no perfil só mostra os posts deletados nos últimos 60 dias, não?